# How to compare record in one table equal to another table using VBscript

Tags: sql-server, checkbox, vbscript, asp-classic

My system require me to use VbScript

**My Situation is**
I have 2 table, named CoverTypes(coverID,coverName data) and InsuCover(selected CoverID and coverName data by user).

I want to display all the data in CoverTypes with checkbox (is checked) if the data is also in insuCover table, and unchecked if there is no same data

**What I did so far is**

- My Query
  coverTypes.Open "SELECT * FROM preregister.coverType", conn, 1
  insuCover.Open "SELECT * FROM insuCover where insuranceReqId = '"& insFireReqID&"'",conn, 1

**Code to Display**

```
                                    <% Do While Not coverTypes.EOF%>
                                    <% if insuCover("coverId") = coverTypes("coverID") then%>
                                       <label id="coverID" name="coverNm"><%=coverTypes("coverNm")%></label>
                                       <input checked ="True" id="item_isSelected" name="item.isSelected" type="checkbox" value="<%=coverTypes("coverId")%>" /><br>
                                     <% else %>
                                       <label id="coverID" name="coverNm"><%=coverTypes("coverNm")%></label>
                                       <input id="item_isSelected" name="item.isSelected" type="checkbox" value="<%=coverTypes("coverId")%>" /><br>
                                    <% end if%>
                                <% coverTypes.MoveNext %>
                                <% Loop %>
```

**The problem is** 
Currently only one checkbox is selected since I do not loop insuCover, but when I loop 2 table and compare, all the data get repeated many times. 
How should I display all the data in CoverTypes and make the checkbox to true if the data is also present in insuCover table?

Thank you.

Comment: I would start by using the sql statement to complete the comparison and return the result as a 1 or 0 for each row (I have assumed that you wish all rows returned as some are checked and others not), and then set the checkbox to .checked if the result of that row is 1. This will simplify the loop and cover each row of the dataset.

Comment: yes ur assumption is right, but can you show me one example because I am quite blurr where to put the sql statement 0_o

Answer (score 0):

I created the tables using just the two columns you provided, ignoring the insuranceReqId column.

The basic statement would link both tables using the coverID, with a LEFT join that will return all values from CoverTypes table, and return the the NULLs from the insuCover where the coverID's are not present. With a simple CASE statement we can test if the data is present in the second table and output a suitable column either as 1 (checked) or 0 (unchecked) that you can use to determine the .checked state of the checkbox on the UI.

```
SELECT p.coverID, p.coverName, CASE WHEN i.coverID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END IsChecked, i.coverID, i.coverName
FROM preregister.coverType p
LEFT JOIN InsuCover i ON p.coverID = i.coverID
```

You can ignore the last two columns in the output as they are only there to check the results visually.